# Git clone private repository during build hangs

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops project which contains scripts used in other Devops projects. This (CICD) project needs to be cloned during build. I've setup that any consuming build pipeline has **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** enabled + environment variable **system.prefergit** set to **true**. The clone Uri has this format: `https://%SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%@xxx.visualstudio.com/xxx%20CICD/_git/xxx%20CICD -b develop cicd`

When I change the CICD projects visibility from private to public things work ok. But I'm not sure what security changes I need to apply AND keep this CICD project private...? I temporarily solved my problem by creating/publishing the CICD project as artefact but I prefer to clone the repository.

Comment: might it be related to whitelisting IPs?

Comment: all the projects are hosted on Azure Devops online